# Aspect ratio incorrect imported image unity editor script

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, textures, aspect-ratio

I have written a script that should make sure the aspect ratio of my image stays the same when i import it into unity.
This is the script:

```
public class PostprocessImages : AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPostprocessTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        textureImporter.npotScale = TextureImporterNPOTScale.None;
        textureImporter.mipmapEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

the script is located in the Editor folder in Assets.
But when i import an image i get the following result:

[image]

this is definitly not what i am looking for.
It should look like this:

[image]

But when i just go to the inspector of the imported image and change a random setting and hit apply the texture does get the proper aspect ratio back. And the settings i modified in the code. Are correct when i inspect the image. But the image doesnt have the right aspect ration..
See image below:

[image]

how would i go about making the image have the right aspect ratio, right from the getgo (when i import it). Because i dont want to do it manual since i have to import hundereds of images.

Let me know if something is unclear so i can clarify.

Comment: Unusual. What happens if you do Assets->ReimportAll ?

Comment: yeah that fixes the problem, still a bit weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this issue but can think of possible fixes.

The first thing to do is to use the `OnPreprocessTexture` function instead of `OnPostprocessTexture`. This will modify the Texture before it is imported.

```
public class PostprocessImages : AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPreprocessTexture()
    {
        TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        textureImporter.npotScale = TextureImporterNPOTScale.None;
        textureImporter.mipmapEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

---

If that doesn't work, call `TextureImporter.SaveAndReimport()` after making the changes on the `Texture` so that Unity will re-import it after making the changes. This is likely to fix the issue. It's worth noting that you need a way to make sure that `TextureImporter.SaveAndReimport()` is called once because calling `TextureImporter.SaveAndReimport()` will trigger `OnPreprocessTexture()`. Without implementing a way to determine this, you will enter into an infinite loop of never ending texture importing. In the example below, I used a `static` `List` to implement that:

```
static List<TextureImporter> importedTex = new List<TextureImporter>();

void OnPostprocessTexture(Texture2D texture)
{
    TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;

    /*Make sure that SaveAndReimport is called once ONLY foe each TextureImporter
     There would be infinite loop if this is not done
     */
    if (!importedTex.Contains(textureImporter))
    {
        textureImporter.npotScale = TextureImporterNPOTScale.None;
        importedTex.Add(textureImporter);
        textureImporter.SaveAndReimport();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get to try this?